# MSbuild 4 with /pp (/preprocess) does not write preprocessed file

Tags: command-line, msbuild

I want to create a pre processed file with msbuild for diagnostic reasons. The documentation states, that I just need to call msbuild with the /pp:Filename switch. So I did:

```
msbuild project.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /pp:out.txt
```

It also creates an 'out.txt' file, so the argument obviously has SOME impact, but the file is empty (size 0, no content). So what could be possible reasons the preprocessed project file isn't written correctly? The project file builds fine though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BTW MSBuild is able to generate a projectfile from any solution. Just set the following environment variable

```
Set MSBuildEmitSolution=1
```

and execute

```
msbuild.exe MySolution.sln.
```

It will generate a MySolution.sln.metaproj which is able to carry the preprocess parameter

Answer (score 8):

the problem is that you're running this on a solution the preprocess parameter only works for projects in MSBuild.

Thorsten

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot :) Thanks.